# How to use header function together with javascript in head section?

Tags: php, javascript, header

I'm using a `header` function in php to redirect to another page on a form submit to avoid resubmiting data to mysql. It worked well until I created a navigation menu in javascript, which puts some code into the head section of the page. After that, when I submit form data, the page did not redirect. Is there some way to fix that?

code is here:
in :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
     (function(){

        var menu1=new Scl.Menu(130);
            menu1.addItem('blabla','sort.php');
            menu1.addItem('hahaha','view.php');
            menu1.addItem('uhuhuh','list.php');
          menu1.dockTo('menu1');
    -->
    </script>

    </head>
```

and:

```
    header("Refresh: 0; url=http://localhost/site/main.php");
```

Comment: Please include some code samples.

Comment: Truly hard without code.

Comment: @DanielMendel now i edited question with part of code

Comment: Is there more code there you have left out or have you accidentally left out the closing `});`?

Comment: @MattAsbury i did not put it in - i have )(); at the end before script tag

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code seems to be missing some closing brackets and parenthesis:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 (function(){
    var menu1=new Scl.Menu(130);
        menu1.addItem('blabla','sort.php');
        menu1.addItem('hahaha','view.php');
        menu1.addItem('uhuhuh','list.php');
      menu1.dockTo('menu1');
 })();                         // added
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Location` instead of `url` and `Refresh`?

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Still not redirects. After submit it displays empty screen on the same page.